# How to get original checkbox value using node id in jsTree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using jsTree. Its working fine but I want to get first node's data value in group of tree.

What I want to do?
When I click on any checkbox, then it will click automaticaly first checkbox

I am getting node id for first element but not getting original checkbox.

I have mention my code below.

```
.on("changed.jstree", function (event, data) {
        if(data.action == 'deselect_node' || data.action == 'select_node'){

            var parentId = $('#'+data.node.id).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var childId = $('#'+parentId+' li:first-child').attr('id');

            var i, j, r = [];

            for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
                if(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).original.permID){
                    r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).original.permID);
                }
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox in a jsTree node is not a checkbox control really, it is an image.
You can get it of course. Based on your script it would go like:

```
var checkBoxImageElement = $('#'+childId).find('.jstree-checkbox')[0];
```

Please check out demo: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/67dkz57o/)